# Django ComboField to change page content

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

I have a model item called `project`, where each project has a Title, Description and a date, which comprises of either Fall or Spring, and a year (eg. Fall 2012, or Spring 2013). I am able to successfully populate a page with all the Projects by using a simple `for` loop in my pages html. However, I want to have a ComboField with a list of dates (that I can specify) in the page so that when a user selects a date, only the Projects with that date will appear on the page.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I use the Django forms items or should I use a HTML `select` tag? If it is better to use a HTML tag, how would one go about accomplishing that?

Comment: It depends, do you want to reload the page or not, in order to apply the filters?

Comment: Reloading the page is fine. If not reloading is a better/more standard practice, then I should be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly coding it, do something like this in your `forms.py`:

```
from django import Forms

from .models import Project

class ProjectFilterForm(forms.Form):

    range = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        oldest = Project.objects.first()
        newest = Project.objects.last()
        if oldest and newest:
            range_choices = []
            for year in range(oldest.date.year, newest.date.year+1):
                range_choices.append('Spring {}'.format(year))
                range_choices.append('Fall {}'.format(year))
            self.fields['range'].choices = range_choices


    def get_filtered_projects(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return []
        choice = self.cleaned_data['range']
        parts = choice.split(' ')
        month_range = [4,5,6,7,8,9] if parts[0] == 'Spring' else [10,11,12,1,2,3]
        year = int(parts[1])
        return Project.objects.filter(date__year=year, date__month__in=month_range)
```

Include the form as part of the template, and in the view use the `get_filtered_projects` to generate the list of projects to show in the rendered page.